# A UDs. nomás se lo/los/les perdono/perdona/perdonan

Tags: pronombres, hispanoamérica, objetos-indirectos, objetos-directos, clíticos

En el caso a) él/ella está perdonando u eximiendo de su obligación a otra persona.

> a) **A ti(OI)** nomás **te** **lo(OD)** perdon**o**(indicativo presente)

> P: ¿Qué cosa me perdonas? R: Que seas impuntual/Tu impuntualidad[lo(OD)]

> P: ¿A quién perdonas? R: A mi[=>A ti(OI)]

En el caso b), c), d) y e) él/ella está perdonando a más de una persona por lo tanto se utiliza 'se' en lugar de 'te'.
El objeto directo se refiere a la impuntualidad.

> b) **A ustedes(OI)** nomás **se** **lo(OD)** perdon**o**(primera persona del singular del indicativo presente)

> P: ¿Qué cosa nos perdonas? R: Que sean impuntuales/Su impuntualidad[=>lo(OD)]

> P: ¿A quiénes perdonas? R: A nosotros[=>A ustedes(OI)]

Me suena mal, pero tal vez sea lo correcto?

En el caso de c) el objeto directo se transforma al plural del objeto indirecto perdiendo su razón de ser **incluso en casos donde el **OD** no es plural**, porque erróneamente se busca una concordancia con **A ustedes(OI)** en lugar de con el **OD**, que tal como dice @Gustavson sólo sería posible si fuera plural, p.ej. "impuntuales y que no me hayan traído un presente(plural)[OD]"

> c) **A ustedes(OI)** nomás **se** **los(OI)** perdon**o**(primera persona del singular del indicativo presente)

> P: ¿Qué cosa nos perdonas? R: Que sean impuntuales/su impuntualidad[=>????]

> P: ¿A quiénes perdonas? R: A nosotros[=>A ustedes(OI)][¿Los(OI)?]

Sin embargo, me suena bien, pero probablemente es incorrecto o algo regional? eso de usar el pronombre átono acusativo con el OI en plural.

> d) **A ustedes(OI)** nomás **se** **les(OI)** perdon**a**(tercera persona **singular** del indicativo presente)

En este caso d) en lugar de que él/ella esté eximiendólos(a ellos) de un castigo la responsabilidad puede recaer en cualquiera por lo tanto puede sonar a queja en lugar de complicidad y por otro lado como con "les" se refiere a ellos, entonces fuerza a que se deba utilizar "perdone**n**"(tercera persona del plural) como en (e), en lugar de "perdon**a**"(primera persona del singular) como en (d)

> e) **A ustedes(OI)** nomás **se** **les(OI)** perdona**n**(tercera persona **plural** del indicativo presente) **sus impuntualidades(OD)**

> P: ¿Qué cosa se nos perdona? R: El que sean impuntuales/su impuntualidad[=>sus impuntualidades(OD)]

> P: ¿A quiénes perdonan? R: A nosotros[=>A ustedes(OI)][¿Les(OI)?]

El problema es que luego de todos esos cambios se va perdiendo correctitud gramatical, pero tal vez se recobre el significado del original.

EDIT:
https://www.rae.es/dpd/pronombres%20personales%20%C3%A1tonos

> b) En el español de muchos países de América, es frecuente, especialmente en registros populares o coloquiales, **trasladar a la forma singular del pronombre átono de acusativo en función de complemento directo el rasgo de plural correspondiente al complemento indirecto**, cuando este va representado por la forma invariable se: «¡No entienden que este es mi espacio, es mi lugar! Cuántas veces quieren que **se los** diga» (Purroy Desertor [Ven. 1989]), en lugar de Cuántas veces quieren que **se lo** diga. Aunque en algunos países esta transferencia indebida se ha extendido incluso entre hablantes cultos, se recomienda evitarla en el habla esmerada.

Eso se lee y escucha incluso a gente esmerada y culta en el español de muchos países de América.

- A él/ella(OI) (ellos) se lo(OD) perdonan = They forgive him/her(OI) for being late(OD)
- A él/ella(OI) (ustedes) se lo(OD) perdonan = You forgive him/her(OI) for being late(OD)
- A él/ella(OI) (ellos) se lo(OD) perdonan = They forgive him/her(OI) for being late(OD)
- A él/ella(OI) (ustedes) se lo(OD) perdonan = You forgive him/her(OI) for being late(OD)
- A él/ella(OI) siempre se le(OD) perdona llegar tarde(OD)  = He/she is always forgiven for being late(OD).
- A él/ella(OI) siempre se la(OI) perdona por llegar tarde(OD) = He/she is always forgiven for being late(OD).
- A ustedes(OI) nomás se lo(OD) perdono = I forgive you, only you(OI), for being late(OD)
- A ustedes(OI) nomás se los(OI) perdono = I forgive you, only you(OI), for being late(OD)
- A ustedes(OI) nomás se la(OI) perdono = I forgive you, only you(OI), for being late(OD)
- A ellos(OI) se les(OI) perdonan llegar tarde(OD) = They(OI) are forgiven for being late(OD)
- A ustedes(OI) se lo(OD) perdono = I forgive you(OI) for being late(OD)
- A ustedes(OI) se les(OI) perdona llegar tarde(OD) = You(OI) are forgiven for being late.
- A ustedes(OI) se los(OI) perdona por llegar tarde = You(OI) are forgiven for being late.
- A ustedes(OI) se las(OD) perdona por llegar tarde = You(OI) are forgiven for coming late.
- A ustedes(OI) nomás Se lo/los/las(OD) perdono = I forgive you(OI) for all of this(OD).
- A ustedes(OI) se les(OI) perdonan sus errores(OD) = They(OI) forgive them(OI) of all of their mistakes(OD)/Others(OI) are forgiven their mistakes(OD).
- Les(OI) voy a perdonar esto(OD)/Se los(OD) voy a perdonar sólo por esta vez/sólo por esta única vez = I forgive you(OI) this(OD) once/this time/just for today.

Comment: No entiendo por nada la pregunta. La palabra correctitud no está en la RAE. Sin embargo,  se dice: Perdoné el error a mi amigo. **Selo perdoné**. O sea: perdonar algo **a alguien**.

Comment: @Lambie Al decir "se lo perdoné" que es pretérito perfecto simple te estás refiriendo a una situación ya acaecida. Entiendo que en inglés sólo haya espacio para un determinado tiempo verbal cuando se trata de traducir "se lo", que es future perfect o preterite según el contexto, pero en español es distinto, al decir "se lo perdono" se refiere a que cada vez que ocurre se lo/los deja pasar, los exime del castigo.

Comment: Hice un error: queria escribir: **Se lo perdoné**. se lo traducido es: him/her for it.  Mi punto no tenia nada que ver con el tiempo verbal sino con el hecho de que uno tenga que decir en español: perdonar algo [COD] a alguien [COI]. ¿ Porqué me hablas del inglés? No tiene nada que ver.

Comment: Correctitud se usa en mi región, hablo del inglés porque tus comentarios se justifican entendiblemente en base a esa lógica. Perdonar algo [OD] a alguien [OI]=> perdonar que sean impuntuales [OD] a UDs [OI] => se LO perdono. Perdonar que hayan sido impuntuales y que no me hayan traído un presente(plural) [OD] a UDs [OI] => Se LOS perdono.

Comment: ¿Cuál es la pregunta? Aquí leo una reflexión, pero no una pregunta.

Comment: Mi comentario no tiene  **nada que ver con el inglés**. ¿ Como te atreves decir esto? Tiene a ver con España. Se perdona algo a alguien. Mira en la **RAE**, lo verás, **perdonar es transitivo**.  "Según he podido leer, ´que el árbitro no ve´, y claro, si el árbitro no ha visto no lo puede pitar, por lo que no tenemos más remedio que **perdonarle el error**. https://www.superdeporte.es/opinion/2007/11/12/arbitro-catalan-12-11-2007-53753733.html

Comment: Perdonar algo a alguien también se dice por acá, como también 'se lo' y 'se los', un regionalismo bastante extendido, tal como su leísmo. Por tus reiteradas intervenciones, no es una crítica, es un halago. Correctitud no es solo en IT, acá lo dicen hasta los pastores evangelicos, lo mismo que pasa con "se los". Más que una reflexión era un pregunta dirigida a Gustavson, el cual me respondió justo lo que quería saber.

Comment: @cocteau El dijo: **Debe usarse "lo" o "la" si el OD es singular, y "los" o "las" si el OD es plural. Del mismo modo, debe usarse "le" si el OI es singular, y "les" si el OI es plural. Es una cuestión de concordancia**. Lo que concuerda exactamente con: **perdonar algo a alguien**. Se los perdono: I forgive him/her for them. [their mistakes] and Se lo perdono. I forgive him/her for it. [whatever it is]

Comment: @Lambie Excelente, ahora sí que sí, precisamente, pero entonces el problema es que mucha gente dice: A UDs se los perdono: I forgive you for all of this, es decir. Usan "los" como una repetición del OI(you=ustedes) en lugar del OD(all of this) o el leísmo, Se les(OI) perdonan: They forgive them of all of their mistakes o others are forgiven their mistakes, lo cual es una búsqueda se hacer la concordancia con el OI en lugar de con el OD. Entonces inconscientemente le preguntaba a Gustavson a raíz de otro hilo, porque ese fenómeno está cruzando fronteras.

Comment: Estás repetiendo la misma cosa várias veces. Es  muy cansado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En la oración:

a) A ti nomás te lo perdono

"a ti" y "te" son en efecto OI y "lo" es OD (el referente debe poder hallarse en el contexto).

En la oración:

b) A ustedes nomás se lo perdono

el análisis es similar a (a): "a ustedes" y "se" son OI y "lo" es OD.

La oración (c) contiene un error muy habitual entre los hablantes, que consiste en trasladar al OD la pluralidad de un OI pronominal "se" que no revela número:

c) A ustedes nomás se los perdono.

O sea, si el OD es singular (ej. que hayan sido impuntuales), la oración correcta es (b). (c) solo sería correcta si el referente del OD fuera plural (ej. que hayan sido impuntuales **y** que no me hayan traído un presente).

La oración (d) es muy diferente de las anteriores:

d) A ustedes nomás se les perdona

y puede tener dos interpretaciones:

d.1. Pasiva con "se" con sujeto tácito (algo, no mencionado, les es perdonado). "A ustedes" y "les" son OI.

d.2. Oración impersonal con leísmo (lo correcto sería: "A ustedes nomás se **los** perdona", en cuyo caso "a ustedes" y "los" son OD de la oración impersonal)

En la oración (e):

e) A ustedes nomás se les perdonan sus impuntualidades

"sus impuntualidades" es sujeto plural de una pasiva con "se" (equivalente a: A ustedes nomás les son perdonadas sus impuntualidades). "A ustedes" y "les" son ambos OI.

En [esta página](https://espanolplus.com/gramatica/errores-concordancia-objeto-indirecto/) pueden encontrarse ejemplos de los dos errores de concordancia que menciono en la respuesta al comentario de Cocteau:

*En la boda de mi prima **le** dije **a mis padres** que mi mujer estaba embarazada. (errónea)

DEBE DECIRSE:

- En la boda de mi prima **les** dije **a mis padres** que mi mujer estaba embarazada. ("les" plural concuerda con "a mis padres")

Les di a tus padres **la noticia**. → *Se **las** di. (errónea)

DEBE DECIRSE:

- Les di a tus padres **la noticia**. → Se **la** di. ("la" singular concuerda con "la noticia")

Comment: Es decir, me dices que "lo" es un error si se traslada a la pluralidad excepto si el OD fuera plural, pero me refiere al uso en hispanoamerica, porque esa traslación lo que busca es una concordancia con el IO para tratar de no desentonar.

Comment: Debe usarse "lo" o "la" si el OD es singular, y "los" o "las" si el OD es plural. Del mismo modo, debe usarse "le" si el OI es singular, y "les" si el OI es plural. Es una cuestión de concordancia.

Comment: Exactamente, y la razón es porque se dice: perdonar algo a alguien. Lo que es la estructura de base.

Answer (score 2):

Entiendo que el pronombre de objeto directo en todas estas oraciones es "lo". La función de objeto indirecto la desempeña "se",  que no es aquí reflexivo, sino que reemplaza a "le" y "les" por eufonía.

Es decir, en teoría, si no existiera este uso eufónico de "se", diríamos:

```
A mí nomás me lo perdonan.
A ti nomás te lo perdono.
*A él/ella/usted nomás le lo perdono.

A nosotros nomás nos lo perdonan.
A vosotros solamente os lo perdono.
*A ellos/ellas/ustedes nomás les lo perdono.
```

Las formas tercera y sexta son incorrectas porque la gramática española exige decir "se lo/la/los/las" en lugar de "le/les lo/la/los/las". Aplicando está regla de sustitución, pasamos de las formas ideales teóricas a las que son en realidad correctas:

```
A él/ella/usted nomás se lo perdono.
A ellos/ellas/ustedes nomás se lo perdono.
```

Comment: Claro, porque es: perdonar algo **a alguien**. Es muy facil.

Comment: Concuerdo hasta cierto punto, porque en el comienzo solo veía correcta "A ellos/ellas/ustedes nomás se LO perdono", pero como dice @Gustavson en esta región(cosa que no alcancé a agregar por complicada pero no menos esclarecedora), "lo" es un error si se traslada a la pluralidad excepto si el OD fuera plural, lo cual no está implícito porque "lo" y "los" referencian a algo que no se menciona, que es p.ej. "el que hayan sido impuntuales y/o que no me hayan traído un presente". En el otro caso, se trata de una oración impersonal con leísmo que es un regionalismo. +1 de igual forma.

Answer (score 0):

"Se los perdono" es incorrecto si el acto perdonado es uno solo.

Con un solo acto perdonado, "Se lo perdono" es correcto sin importar cuántas personas son perdonadas.

Comment: Es entendido que 'lo' es 'la impuntualidad', pero si digo 'se los/las' difícilmente se entiende que es 'la impuntualidad y la ingratitud' sino que ustedes(OI) a menos que diga como 'sus retrasos/llegadas tarde' luego de 'se les perdonan'. 'A UDs(OI) se lo(OD) perdono: I forgive you(OI) for being late' que se diría cuando es algo que se ha estado haciendo o desde ese día se va a seguir haciendo porque si fuera un solo acto diría 'sólo por hoy/just for today' se los voy a perdonar.